# Copy a line matching pattern to beside another matching pattern line using sed

Tags: sed

I want to copy the line containing `www.website.com` into the line containing `thetext`.

For example, I want to transform this input:

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, elit.
Cras eu www.website.com velit vitae
Pellentesque interdum
thetext
Sed ullamcorper tellus
```

into this output:

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, elit.
Cras eu www.website.com velit vitae
Pellentesque interdum
thetextCras eu www.website.com velit vitae
Sed ullamcorper tellus
```

I have no idea how to copy-paste using `sed`. It looks somewhat tricky.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if that's exactly what you want, but:

1. When you see the interesting line (the line containing `www.website.com`), copy it into the hold space.
2. When you see the text to replace (`thetext`), append the contents of the hold space, and
3. clean up the result.

```
sed -e '/www\.website\.com/h' \
    -e '/thetext/{' -e 'G' -e 's/\n//' -e '}'
```

I do recommend turning to awk for anything beyond a plain `s///`.

```
awk '
    /www\.website\.com/ { line=$0 }
    /thetext/ { $0 = $0 line }
    1'
```

Answer (score 2):

You may also use `ed` (here used in the `Bash` shell) to move & join lines as follows:

```
str='
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, elit.
Cras eu www.website.com velit vitae
Pellentesque interdum
thetext
Sed ullamcorper tellus
'

# cf. http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/howto/edit-ed
cat <<-'EOF' | sed -e 's/^ *//' -e 's/ *$//' | ed -s <(echo "$str")
   H
   /www\.website\.com/m/thetext/
   -1,.j
  ,p
  q
EOF
```

If you're going to edit files in-place, `ed` may be your tool of choice.